go vet ./... rejects OpenAPI Generator-generated code with "not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value"
This struct that has been generated by OpenAPI Generator 7.10.0:
type Action struct {
    Name NullableString "json:\"name\" validate:\"regexp=[&#x9; !\\\\x27&amp;&quot;()*+,-.\\/0-9:;&lt;=&gt;?A-Z_a-z\\\\[\\\\]{}|^@#~`]*\""
// [...]
}

fails with this error message when go vet ./... is run:
struct field tag "json:\"name\" validate:\"regexp=[&#x9; !\\\\x27&amp;&quot;()*+,-.\\/0-9:;&lt;=&gt;?A-Z_a-z\\\\[\\\\]{}|^@#~`]*\"" not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value

What is the trouble go vet ./... complains about?

From https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StructTag: By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.
Your validate looks a bit strange. Don't do such things and don't let tools do such things either.

OpenApi is generating unsupported tags, so I would file an issue with that project. If you run a few permutations of your string to debug the problem, you'll find that single backslashes will fail because escape characters are not allowed. your quoted string has "\\", which evaluates as a single backslash. All the backslashes however might be incorrect, because that format is within a nested quoted string, so they need to be double-escaped.

I'm a contributor in Open Api Generator. I'll take a look this week or the next.

Since go struct tags are strings within strings, strconv.Unquote is called twice, making double escapes like \\\\ necessary. You tag contains to few escapes in *+,-.\\/0-9:;, which is invalid.
Generally, as Volker mentioned, having &#x9;...&amp;&quot;...&lt;=&gt; in a validation regex is strange and probably not what you want. Somewhere in your chain something HTML-encoded a string and messed things up.

@JimB is right: there's a problem with Open Api generator. I've started investigating it, in that comment part of the issue Golang pattern validation with regex fails on commas someone opened last month. I think I achieved to generate what me and the opener of the issue believe that should be generated inside validate:regex="..." but go vet ./.... The opener of the issue might be right: maybe it's go-validator v2 that is flawed.

Part of last comment is missing: "but go vet ./... still refuses the generation"

@MarcLeBihan as mentioned, a single \\ inside a struct tag is invalid.

Thanks. With the help of the opener of the issue and yours, I think I can solve this issue soon.

@MarcLeBihan … should have been \\ , stack overflow swallowed one escape. Feed free to upvote the answers that helped you ;)

I gladly upvote your answer, yes. But notice that I've found a bug inside open api generator, I'm currently correcting it, and I'm receiving a -3 downvote for that all...

@MarcLeBihan Th Go community tends to be a little bit overly aggressive here, you could discuss this on Meta. Otherwise, TBH, I'm not sure how OpenAPI generator could do something like that - this seems to be a truly piece of broken software to me.
